# ReactJS - based on input value - auto set the selection option

Tags: reactjs

My goal is, when you type in the input field: 1, then select dropdown should set the value to: First Value. Or vice versa when input field given value of 2. So this should happen on the `onKeyUp` event of the input field, based on those input field values, the select dropdown should be auto selected to its appropriate selection option

```
handleKeyUp(e) {
  if (inputValue == 1) {
    this.setState({ mySelectOptions: e.target.value });
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="formID">
      <form>
        <div className="inputSection">
          <input
            name="myInput"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ myInput: e.target.value })}
            onKeyUP={this.handleKeyUp}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="selectOptions">
          <select
            value={this.state.value}
            onKeyUp={e => this.setState({ mySelectOptions: e.target.value })}
          >
            <option value="firstValue">First Value</option>
            <option value="secondValue">Second Value</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue please? What's your goal? What is the problem?

Comment: Goal is, when you type in the input  field: 1, then select dropdown should set the value to: First Value.
Or vise versa when input field given value of 2. 
So this should happen on the onKeyUp event of the input field, based on those input field values, the select dropdown should be auto selected to its appropriate selection option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code, and it's working as you explained in your description, there was some issues with your code, like this `onKeyUP` should be `onKeyUp` and instead of calling `setState` function when change happen, it's better to use the `handleKeyUp`, I recommend using console/IDE while writing code to guide you during development process instead of wondering why things are not working as expected.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: "firstValue"
    };
    this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyUp(value) {
    console.log(value);
    if (value === "1") {
      this.setState({ selectedOption: "firstValue" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ selectedOption: "secondValue" });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="formID">
        <form>
          <div className="inputSection">
            <input
              name="myInput"
              defaultValue="1"
              onKeyUp={e => this.handleKeyUp(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="selectOptions">
            <select
              value={this.state.selectedOption}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value })}
            >
              <option value="firstValue">First Value</option>
              <option value="secondValue">Second Value</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason getting following error message on this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of ''value" of undefined. 
error pointing to this line of code: onKeyUp={e => this.handleKeyUp(e.target.value)}

Comment: I ran it on sandbox without having this issue https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-shannon-nhh2j

Comment: replace `e.target.value` with `e.target` and try it again please.

Comment: ended up working as original version: e.target.value. It just page needed clear of cookies/cache. Another quick question if you don't mind:) iterating over this array list not working: json format for{ this.state.myData} looks like this: lists:[{ id: '1', item_name: 'Item1'', other_listings: {item_id: '3', item_category: 'Catetegory1'} }] render() return ( <div> <table> {this.state.myData.map((info) =>( <tr><th>id number</th><td>{id}</td> ))} </table> </div> )